# Return the previous month of a specific date in a year

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following code that I used to calculate the previous month of a date:

```
from dateutil import parser, relativedelta
import datetime

@staticmethod
def get_previous_month(date):
    previous_month = date - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
    return previous_month
```

I thought this worked but I don't think it takes the year into account.

I'm passing in datetime objects as the argument.

For `datetime.date(1990, 4, 30)` the previous month should be:

`datetime.date(1990, 3, 31)` but it returns:

`datetime.date(1990, 3, 30)`

I also tried specifying the year but to no avail.

Comment: How is it supposed to know that you want 3/31, and not 3/30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the previous month of `datetime.date(1990, 4, 30)` **IS** 3, so the library is **actually correct** returning `datetime.date(1990, 3, 30)`.

The problem is in the question - what you really want is **last day of previous month**.

```
def get_last_day_of_previous_month(d):
    return d.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Ah yes.. that's what I was looking for. Thank you.